# How to delete folder using msbuild batch

Tags: asp.net, msbuild

i have created on batch "del.bat".below is my batch script which is define in "del.bat"

I wanted to delete folder using batch after clicking "del.bat".when i am go to click "del.bat",nothing is happened.please let me know how to run it

```
<Project>
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

<Target Name="clean_folders">
         <RemoveDir Directories="D:\projectdemo\crick\Cart"
               ContinueOnError="true" />
    </Target>

</Project>
c: 
cd C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC
MSBuild.exe D:\projectdemo\demo.csproj /t:clean_folders>D:\projectdemo\output.txt
```

Comment: can you post the output from msbuild when your run it from the commandline instead of from the batch file?

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild is not located in the Visual Studio VC folder. This is the default folder where Command Prompt point to : the VS tools are located here.

MSBuild is not part of Visual Studio but of the .NET Framework.

MSBuild 4 (Visual Studio 2010) x86 is located in the Framework v4.0 folder :

> "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe"
>   D:\projectdemo\demo.csproj /t:clean_folders >
>   D:\projectdemo\output.txt

Comment: it's probably better to first `call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86` in the batch file to make sure everything is setup correctly, then just use `MSBuild` since it will be in the PATH

Comment: It can be done if needed but the `PATH`s and environment variables registered by the `vcvars*` scripts are for Visual Studio tools utilization purposes. If the goal is just to call a MSBuild task, it is a bit overdone to call this batch since MSBuild is generally located in one known place. And if MSBuild directory may not change, Visual Studio dir can. At last, you can `call "%VS100COMNTOOLS%VCVarsQueryRegistry.bat" 32bit No64bit` and then use `%FrameworkDIR32%\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe ...` but again, VS 2010 must be present.